# How to programmatically add multiple strings to one line in a multiple column ListView

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, multiple-columns

So I'm new to WPF as I'm more familiar with WinForms, But for the sake of drawing performance and good looking UI I switched to WPF, I have no experience in XAML but I'm working my things out.

I have a `ListView` which works as a playlist for my Media Player App. Adding Multiple Data in one line of multiple columns wasn't a problem in WinForms, I just had to add a `ListViewItem` and fill it's `SubItems` , but in WPF it's a problem, the `ListViewItem` doesn't have `SubItems` property nor the `ListView`, I tried multiple questions from Stack Overflow and other website which didn't help me , and it was all about `DisplayMemberBinding` but I still can't / don't know how to reference it in my code.

XAML for `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="Playlist_Main" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="#" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Num}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Album" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Track Num" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Track}"/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Main Code

```
Playlist_Main.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({Playlist_Main.Items.Count + 1, Info(0), Info(1), Info(2), Info(3), Info(4)}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings in your `ListView` / `GridView` require an item type that exposes properties for `Num`, `Title`, and so on. You have to expose a collection of that item type and assign or bind it to the `ItemsSource` property.

Create a model for an item in your playlist. The following example implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0) interface that enables bindings to update through the [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-5.0) event if a property value changes. If your properties are read-only or you do not need to update values at runtime, you do not have to implement it.

```
public class PlaylistItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private int _num;
   private string _title;
   private string _artist;
   private string _album;
   private int _year;
   private int _track;

   public PlaylistItem(int num, string title, string artist, string album, int year, int track)
   {
      Num = num;
      Title = title;
      Artist = artist;
      Album = album;
      Year = year;
      Track = track;
   }

   public int Num
   {
      get => _num;
      set
      {
         if (_num == value)
            return;

         _num = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public string Title
   {
      get => _title;
      set
      {
         if (_title == value)
            return;

         _title = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public string Artist
   {
      get => _artist;
      set
      {
         if (_artist == value)
            return;

         _artist = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public string Album
   {
      get => _album;
      set
      {
         if (_album == value)
            return;

         _album = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public int Year
   {
      get => _year;
      set
      {
         if (_year == value)
            return;

         _year = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public int Track
   {
      get => _track;
      set
      {
         if (_track == value)
            return;

         _track = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

In a code-behind approach, you could create a collection of `PlaylistItem`s. Use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) that implements the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-5.0) interface, if you want to reflect changes to the collection in the user interface, e.g. adding or removing items. The `ObservableCollection<T>` does that automatically through the [`CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged?view=net-5.0) event. If your list is not modified at runtime, you can use any other collection.

```
var playlistItems = new ObservableCollection<PlaylistItem>();

playlistItems.Add(new PlaylistItem(1, "Enter Sandman", "Metallica", "Metallica", 1991, 1));
// ...add other playlist items.
```

You could assign this collection directly to the `ListView` e.g. in the constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   var playlistItems = // ...create the items collection or load them from somewhere.
   Playlist_Main.ItemsSource = playlistItems;
}
```

A different approach is creating a public property in your code-behind. I assume it is the `MainWindow`.

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      PlaylistItems = // ...create the items collection or load them from somewhere.
   }

   public ObservableCollection<PlaylistItem> PlaylistItems { get; }
}
```

You would bind this collection in XAML using a `RelativeSource` binding to the window.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
```

As you can see, there are multiple approaches, even more. The best, in my opinion, would be to use the MVVM pattern. For that, you would create a view model for your main window that contains the collection.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MainViewModel()
   {
      PlaylistItems = // ...create the items collection or load them from somewhere.
   }

   public ObservableCollection<PlaylistItem> PlaylistItems { get; }

   // ...other properties and methods.
}
```

Next you would set an instance of this view model as `DataContext` of your window.

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Then you can bind to the collection like this. The data context (`MainViewModel`) is inherited automatically.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PlaylistItems}">
```

This pattern helps you to separate the user interface from the data and business logic. As you can see, there are no references from the view model to the view, only properties that expose data that can be bound.

Further resources for learning:

- [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0)
- [How to: Create and Bind to an ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Since I am unfamiliar with VB.NET, the code is in C#, but it is not very complex and the concepts apply regardless of the underlying language, so I hope this helps you.

Comment: I implemented and converted everything from your code to VB.net no errors , but when I add a `PlaylistItem` to the list it : 1- Only fills 3 columns from the list view(#,Year,Track Num) 2- No matter what value i put it fills it with 0
Here is an image of the problem : [Click Me!](https://i.imgur.com/5Wfo1NX.png)
Thanks for your help again I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AnesHamdani Which approach did you use? Those are the default values, empty for `string` and `0` for `int`. Are there any binding errors in your output window?

Comment: i added 
`        Console.WriteLine(Me.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(propertyName)`
but `OnPropertyChanged` is not even called

Comment: I managed to solve it, and now it's working perfectly , the error for the 0 for int and empty for string was because the `public PlaylistItem` parameters were conflicting with the properties names so i changed the parameters names and now it's working perfectly , Than You!!!